# flask reading text file and view it in html page as lines

Tags: python, html, file, flask

my python code

```
from flask import Flask,render_template,request
import os,glob

f=open('filename.txt','r')
g= f.read()


app= Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html',n=g)


if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

and this is my html code

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>admin</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>{{n}}</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

it's shows me the output as one single line but I want it to show the lines Below each other.

Comment: see how to iterate over a list in jinja template you will get the idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more of an HTML problem.

You'll need to introduce HTML line breaks (`<br>`) in the rendering of the object.

Try replacing `\n` in your file w/ `<br>` (e.g., `g = g.replace('\n', '<br>')`).
(Or you can insert breaks programatically)

Also, in your HTML, change `{{ n }}` to `{{ n|safe }}`.

You may want to read more on Jinja formatting here: https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/templates/

Comment: That's a clever approach. But in this case I think that ```<pre>``` is much easier to implement and will do the job perfectly.

Comment: Wasn't familiar with that tag!

Comment: Thank you so much this solved my problem 100%, I tried ( g = g.replace('\n', '<br>')).

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is an HTML tag called `pre`

Try this :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>admin</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <pre>{{n}}</pre>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre

Comment: I think it was my python code when I tried to do g = g.replace('\n', '<br>')). as I was told it's worked 100% correctly, thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

You should have more information in this question:

- where are you viewing this output?  in a terminal, in the browser after running flask's wsgi app?
- are you trying to view the raw html text or formatted html like a web browser?
- what version of Flask are you using?

Comment: Hi Robert, just FYI I believe this should not be answer, but better suit to be a comment instead :)